# realpath substitute with --relative-to and --relative-base support

Tags: bash, macos

In a bash 3 script for OSX machines, I needed the functional equivalent of the [`realpath` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html), complete with support for the `--relative-to` and `--relative-base` options.

I would normally just install the [homebrew `coreutils` formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils), but I need this script to work when bootstrapping a new machine with no network or XCode available yet. So the code below includes a  replacement implementation that's only used when the command is not already installed. Normal usage would be

```bsh
for resolved_path in $(realpath [--relative-to=...] [--relative-base=...] [one or more paths]); do
    # ...
done
```

It's meant to be used as a sourced library (`. realpathlib.bash`), but if run directly with `bash realpathlib.bash` it runs a simple test suite.

I've been picking up bash best practices as I went along, but would love feedback on all aspects, such as naming conventions and other coding style aspects, techniques, problems I've overlooked, etc.

```bsh
# shellcheck shell=bash
set -euo pipefail

_contains() {
    # return true if first argument is present in the other arguments
    local elem value

    value="$1"
    shift

    for elem in "$@"; do 
        if [[ $elem == "$value" ]]; then
            return 0
        fi
    done
    return 1
}

_canonicalize_filename_mode() {
    # resolve any symlink targets, GNU readlink -f style
    # where every path component except the last should exist and is
    # resolved if it is a symlink. This is essentially a re-implementation
    # of canonicalize_filename_mode(path, CAN_ALL_BUT_LAST).
    # takes the path to canonicalize as first argument

    local path result component seen
    seen=()
    path="$1"
    result="/"
    if [[ $path != /* ]]; then  # add in current working dir if relative
        result="$PWD"
    fi
    while [[ -n $path ]]; do
        component="${path%%/*}"
        case "$component" in
            '') # empty because it started with /
                path="${path:1}" ;;
            .)  # ./ current directory, do nothing
                path="${path:1}" ;;
            ..) # ../ parent directory
                if [[ $result != "/" ]]; then  # not at the root?
                    result="${result%/*}"      # then remove one element from the path
                fi
                path="${path:2}" ;;
            *)
                # add this component to the result, remove from path
                if [[ $result != */ ]]; then
                    result="$result/"
                fi
                result="$result$component"
                path="${path:${#component}}"
                # element must exist, unless this is the final component
                if [[ $path =~ [^/] && ! -e $result ]]; then
                    echo "$1: No such file or directory" >&2
                    return 1
                fi
                # if the result is a link, prefix it to the path, to continue resolving
                if [[ -L $result ]]; then
                    if _contains "$result" "${seen[@]+"${seen[@]}"}"; then
                        # we've seen this link before, abort
                        echo "$1: Too many levels of symbolic links" >&2
                        return 1
                    fi
                    seen+=("$result")
                    path="$(readlink "$result")$path"
                    if [[ $path = /* ]]; then
                        # if the link is absolute, restart the result from /
                        result="/"
                    elif [[ $result != "/" ]]; then
                        # otherwise remove the basename of the link from the result
                        result="${result%/*}"
                    fi
                elif [[ $path =~ [^/] && ! -d $result ]]; then
                    # otherwise all but the last element must be a dir
                    echo "$1: Not a directory" >&2
                    return 1
                fi
                ;;
        esac
    done
    echo "$result"
}

_realpath() {
    local relative_to relative_base seenerr path

    relative_to=
    relative_base=
    seenerr=

    while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
        case $1 in
            "--relative-to="*)
                relative_to=$(_canonicalize_filename_mode "${1#*=}")
                shift 1;;
            "--relative-base="*)
                relative_base=$(_canonicalize_filename_mode "${1#*=}")
                shift 1;;
            *)
                break;;
        esac
    done

    if [[
        -n $relative_to
        && -n $relative_base
        && ${relative_to#${relative_base}/} == "$relative_to"
    ]]; then
        # relative_to is not a subdir of relative_base -> ignore both
        relative_to=
        relative_base=
    elif [[ -z $relative_to && -n $relative_base ]]; then
        # if relative_to has not been set but relative_base has, then
        # set relative_to from relative_base, simplifies logic later on
        relative_to="$relative_base"
    fi

    for path in "$@"; do
        if ! real=$(_canonicalize_filename_mode "$path"); then
            seenerr=1
            continue
        fi

        # make path relative if so required
        if [[
            -n $relative_to
            && ( # path must not be outside relative_base to be made relative
                -z $relative_base || ${real#${relative_base}/} != "$real"
            )
        ]]; then
            local common_part parentrefs

            common_part="$relative_to"
            parentrefs=
            while [[ ${real#${common_part}/} == "$real" ]]; do
                common_part="$(dirname "$common_part")"
                parentrefs="..${parentrefs:+/$parentrefs}"
            done

            if [[ $common_part != "/" ]]; then
                real="${parentrefs:+${parentrefs}/}${real#${common_part}/}"
            fi
        fi

        echo "$real"
    done
    if [[ $seenerr ]]; then
        return 1
    fi
}

if ! command -v realpath > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    # realpath is not available on OSX unless you install the `coreutils` brew
    realpath() { _realpath "$@"; }
fi

if [[ $0 == "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]]; then
    assert_equal() {
        local result
        while read -r result; do
            if [[ $result != "$1" ]]; then
                echo -e "\033[0;31mFAIL\033[0m"
                echo -e "expected\n\t$1\ngot\n\t$result"
                exit 2
            fi
            shift 1
        done
        # any expected results left over?
        if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
            echo -e "\033[0;31mFAIL\033[0m"
            echo "expected more results"
            printf '\t- %s\n' "$@"
            exit 2
        fi
        echo -e "\033[0;32mOK\033[0m"
    }

    testdir=$(mktemp -d -t "${0##*/}_tests")
    # canonicalize testdir with pwd -P (no .. components, so sufficient)
    pushd "$testdir"
    testdir=$(pwd -P)
    popd >/dev/null

    cleanup() {
        rm -rf "$testdir"
    }
    trap cleanup EXIT

    mkdir -p "$testdir/foo/bar/baz"
    mkdir -p "$testdir/foobar"
    touch "$testdir/target"
    touch "$testdir/foo/target"
    touch "$testdir/foo/bar/target"
    touch "$testdir/foobar/target"
    ln -s "../link" "$testdir/foo/bar/baz/link"
    ln -s "../link" "$testdir/foo/bar/link"
    ln -s "../target" "$testdir/foo/link"
    ln -s "circular2" "$testdir/foo/circular1"
    ln -s "circular1" "$testdir/foo/circular2"
    ln -s "../foo/bar" "$testdir/foobar/dirlink"

    echo -en "chained symlinks:\t"
    _realpath "$testdir/foo/bar/baz/link" \
        | assert_equal "$testdir/target"

    echo -en "circular symlinks:\t"
    { _realpath "$testdir/foo/circular1" 2>&1 || echo "error exit"; } \
        | assert_equal \
            "$testdir/foo/circular1: Too many levels of symbolic links" \
            "error exit"

    echo -en "symlink and .. combo:\t"
    _realpath "$testdir/foobar/dirlink/../target" \
        | assert_equal \
            "$testdir/foo/target"

    echo -en "non-existing path:\t"
    { _realpath "$testdir/nonesuch/foo" 2>&1 || echo "error exit"; } \
        | assert_equal \
            "$testdir/nonesuch/foo: No such file or directory" \
            "error exit"

    echo -en "file as directory:\t"
    { _realpath "$testdir/target/foo" 2>&1 || echo "error exit"; } \
        | assert_equal \
            "$testdir/target/foo: Not a directory" \
            "error exit"

    echo -en "relative paths:\t\t"
    pushd "$testdir/foo" > /dev/null
    _realpath \
            "bar/target" \
            "../target" \
            "target" \
            "$testdir/./foo/../foobar/target" \
        | assert_equal \
            "$testdir/foo/bar/target" \
            "$testdir/target" \
            "$testdir/foo/target" \
            "$testdir/foobar/target"
    popd > /dev/null

    echo -en "relative-base inside:\t"
    _realpath --relative-base="$testdir/foo" "$testdir/foo/bar/target" \
        | assert_equal "bar/target"

    echo -en "relative-base outside:\t"
    _realpath --relative-base="$testdir/foo/bar" "$testdir/foo/target" \
        | assert_equal "$testdir/foo/target"

    echo -en "--r-base name prefix:\t"
    _realpath --relative-base="$testdir/foo" "$testdir/foobar/target" \
        | assert_equal "$testdir/foobar/target"

    echo -en "--r-base extra /-s:\t"
    _realpath --relative-base="$testdir//foo//" "$testdir/foo/target" \
        | assert_equal "target"

    echo -en "--r-base relative:\t"
    pushd "$testdir/foo/bar" > /dev/null
    _realpath --relative-base="../../foo" "$testdir/foo/bar/target" \
        | assert_equal "bar/target"
    popd > /dev/null

    echo -en "multiple --r-base:\t"
    _realpath --relative-base="$testdir/foo" \
            "$testdir/foo/target" \
            "$testdir/target" \
            "$testdir/foo/bar/target" \
        | assert_equal \
            "target" \
            "$testdir/target" \
            "bar/target"

    echo -en "--r-base divergent:\t"
    _realpath --relative-base="$testdir" "/dev/null" \
        | assert_equal "/dev/null"

    echo -en "relative-to inside:\t"
    _realpath --relative-to="$testdir/foo" "$testdir/foo/bar/target" \
        | assert_equal "bar/target"

    echo -en "relative-to outside:\t"
    _realpath --relative-to="$testdir/foo/bar" "$testdir/target" \
        | assert_equal "../../target"

    echo -en "--r-to name prefix:\t"
    _realpath --relative-to="$testdir/foo" "$testdir/foobar/target" \
        | assert_equal "../foobar/target"

    echo -en "--r-to extra /-s:\t"
    _realpath --relative-to="$testdir//foo//" "$testdir/foo/target" \
        | assert_equal "target"

    echo -en "--r-to relative:\t"
    pushd "$testdir/foo" > /dev/null
    _realpath --relative-to="../foobar" "$testdir/foo/target" \
        | assert_equal "../foo/target"
    popd > /dev/null

    echo -en "multiple --r-to:\t"
    _realpath --relative-to="$testdir/foo" \
            "$testdir/foo/target" \
            "$testdir/target" \
            "$testdir/foo/bar/target" \
        | assert_equal \
            "target" \
            "../target" \
            "bar/target"

    echo -en "combined inside both:\t"
    _realpath --relative-base="$testdir" --relative-to="$testdir/foo" "$testdir/foo/bar/target" \
        | assert_equal "bar/target"

    echo -en "combined outside one:\t"
    _realpath --relative-base="$testdir" --relative-to="$testdir/foo/bar" "$testdir/target" \
        | assert_equal "../../target"

    echo -en "combined outside both:\t"
    _realpath --relative-base="$testdir/foo" --relative-to="$testdir/foo/bar" "$testdir/target" \
        | assert_equal "$testdir/target"

    echo -en "multiple combined:\t"
    _realpath --relative-base="$testdir/foo" --relative-to="$testdir/foo/bar" \
            "$testdir/foo/target" "$testdir/target" "$testdir/foo/bar/target" \
        | assert_equal \
            "../target" \
            "$testdir/target" \
            "target"

    echo -en "combined errorcase:\t"
    # -base should be a parent path of -to. If not, the arguments are ignored
    _realpath --relative-base="$testdir/foo/bar" --relative-to="$testdir/foo" "$testdir/foo/bar/target" \
        | assert_equal "$testdir/foo/bar/target"
fi
```

Comment: To me this seems like an XY problem. Why can't you just use the "[Multiple installations](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation)" section to get homebrew? Ship the install script with the tarball and you can bootstrap from there.

Comment: @Peilonrayz that’d still require a network connection or a lot more work to package up all dependent bottles: https://discourse.brew.sh/t/installing-homebrew-without-internet/3321/4. Bootstrapping can’t always rely on a network connection.

Comment: I wouldn't call 'compiling with a `--build-from-source` flag once and reusing the same pre-installed package' a lot more work. Seems like a lot less work then writing your own bootstrap ecosystem. With some use of chroot you could probably remove any need for the flag either.

Comment: @Peilonrayz: packaging up and maintaining a minimal network-less homebrew and xcode setup would be more work. This is ~150 lines (not counting tests), and was the only missing tool.

Comment: I fail to see how this <20 lines script (not counting tests) I have is _more work_ than maintaining a ~150 line script (not counting tests). Takes about 10 minutes to build the package and once built the 382M package runs even without internet. I guess I just lack the ability to do real bootstrapping.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> # shellcheck shell=bash
> ```

You're using Shellcheck.  That makes me happy.  :-)

> ```
> set -euo pipefail
> ```

Similarly, this is a good set of options to enable.

> ```
>     for elem in "$@"; do
> ```

`in "$@"` is redundant here (though it does no harm).

> ```
>     [[ $elem == "$value" ]]
> ```

I'd use plain `[` there, and quote both variables, as this is the kind of function I might later want to transplant to a plain POSIX shell script.

> ```
>     case $1 in
>         "--relative-to="*)
>             relative_to=$(_canonicalize_filename_mode "${1#*=}")
>             shift 1;;
>         "--relative-base="*)
>             relative_base=$(_canonicalize_filename_mode "${1#*=}")
>             shift 1;;
> ```

The argument to `shift` is redundant, and wasn't used in the other function.  Try to be consistent!

---

## The tests

... seem happy here:

```
/tmp/user/1000/242050.sh_tests.CbF6 ~/stackexchange/review
chained symlinks:   [0;32mOK[0m
circular symlinks:  [0;32mOK[0m
symlink and .. combo:   [0;32mOK[0m
non-existing path:  [0;32mOK[0m
file as directory:  [0;32mOK[0m
relative paths:     [0;32mOK[0m
relative-base inside:   [0;32mOK[0m
relative-base outside:  [0;32mOK[0m
--r-base name prefix:   [0;32mOK[0m
--r-base extra /-s: [0;32mOK[0m
--r-base relative:  [0;32mOK[0m
multiple --r-base:  [0;32mOK[0m
--r-base divergent: [0;32mOK[0m
relative-to inside: [0;32mOK[0m
relative-to outside:    [0;32mOK[0m
--r-to name prefix: [0;32mOK[0m
--r-to extra /-s:   [0;32mOK[0m
--r-to relative:    [0;32mOK[0m
multiple --r-to:    [0;32mOK[0m
combined inside both:   [0;32mOK[0m
combined outside one:   [0;32mOK[0m
combined outside both:  [0;32mOK[0m
multiple combined:  [0;32mOK[0m
combined errorcase: [0;32mOK[0m
```

> ```
>            echo -e "\033[0;31mFAIL\033[0m"
> ```

Please don't hard-code terminal codes in messages like that - you don't know that it will be run in the same terminal type (it looks very ugly in my Emacs `compilation` buffer).  And avoid non-standard `echo -e`.

On my (Debian) system, `mktemp -d -t "${0##*/}_tests"` fails:

> ```
> mktemp: too few X's in template ‘242050.sh_tests’
> ```

It's easily fixed:

```
testdir=$(mktemp -d -t "${0##*/}_tests.XXXX")
```

> ```
> pushd "$testdir"
> testdir=$(pwd -P)
> popd >/dev/null
> ```

`pushd` and `popd` are good for interactive use, but less well suited to scripts (as evident by the need to discard output).  Use plain `cd` instead:

```
testdir=$(cd "$testdir" && pwd -P)
```

I'm surprised not to see any tests with `.` or `..` components in `--relative-*` options.

I'm also surprised that we don't enter the test directory and provide arguments that are relative rather than absolute.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of the above, with the base `realpath` bit redone in a simpler way, lots of other tweaks, and most importantly, instead of using an "expected" value for the tests, just run them straight against `realpath`.  It makes it harder to test properly (I used a locally-built install of `bash` with the same version as on macos, and to test on a macos you'll need to use the original bash with a `realpath` installed). But the upside of it is that there's no need to go over the tests carefully -- since it should just follow whatever `realpath` is doing directly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

# based on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/242050

failwith() { { echo -n "error: "; printf "%s\n" "$@"; } 1>&2; exit 1; }

rpath() { # mimics a sane `realpath` for insane OSs that lack one
  local relbase="" relto=""
  while [[ x"${1-}" = x-* ]]; do case "$1" in
    ( "--relative-base="* ) relbase="$(rpath ${1#*=})" ;;
    ( "--relative-to="* )   relto="$(rpath ${1#*=})" ;;
    ( * ) failwith "unrecognized option '$1'"
  esac; shift; done
  if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]; then failwith "missing operand"; fi
  if [[ -n "$relto" && -n "$relbase" && "${relto#"$relbase/"}" = "$relto" ]]; then
    # relto is not a subdir of relbase => ignore both
    relto="" relbase=""
  elif [[ -z "$relto" && -n "$relbase" ]]; then
    # relbase is set but relto isn't => set relto from relbase to simplify
    relto="$relbase"
  fi
  local p d f n=0 up common PWD0="$PWD"
  for p in "$@"; do
    cd "$PWD0"
    while (( n++ < 50 )); do
      d="$(dirname "$p")"
      if [[ ! -e "$d" ]]; then failwith "$p: No such file or directory"; fi
      if [[ ! -d "$d" ]]; then failwith "$p: Not a directory"; fi
      cd -P "$d"
      f="$(basename "$p")"
      if [[ -h "$f" ]]; then p="$(readlink "$f")"; continue; fi
      # done getting the realpath
      local r="$PWD/$f"
      if [[ -n "$relto" && ( -z "$relbase" || "${r#"$relbase/"}" != "$r" ) ]]; then
        common="$relto" up=""
        while [[ "${r#"$common/"}" = "$r" ]]; do
          common="${common%/*}" up="..${up:+"/$up"}"
        done
        if [[ "$common" != "/" ]]; then
          r="${up:+"$up"/}${r#"$common/"}"
        fi
      fi
      cd "$PWD0"; echo "$r"; continue 2
    done
    cd "$PWD0"; failwith "$1: Too many levels of symbolic links"
  done
}

###############################################################################

t="/tmp/$$"
errors=0
cleanup() {
  rm -rf "$t"
  if ((errors)); then echo "$errors failures"
  else echo "All OK"; fi
}
try() {
  label="$1"; shift
  echo -n "$label {$*}"
  r="$((rpath "$@") 2>&1 || :)"
  real="$(realpath "$@" 2>&1 || :)"
  if [[ "$real" = "realpath: "* ]]; then real="error: ${real#*: }"; real="${real%%$'\n'*}"; fi
  if [[ "$r" = "$real" ]]; then echo " OK"
  else
    (( errors++ )) || :
    echo " FAIL:"
    echo "  expected: $real"
    echo "  got:      $r"
  fi
}
trap cleanup EXIT

mkdir -p "$t/foo/bar/baz"
mkdir -p "$t/foobar"
touch "$t/target"
touch "$t/foo/target"
touch "$t/foo/bar/target"
touch "$t/foobar/target"
ln -s "../link" "$t/foo/bar/baz/link"
ln -s "../link" "$t/foo/bar/link"
ln -s "../target" "$t/foo/link"
ln -s "circular2" "$t/foo/circular1"
ln -s "circular1" "$t/foo/circular2"
ln -s "../foo/bar" "$t/foobar/dirlink"

try "no args"
try "bogus flag" --bogus
try "chained symlinks"      "$t/foo/bar/baz/link"
try "circular symlinks"     "$t/foo/circular1"
try "symlink and .. combo"  "$t/foobar/dirlink/../target"
try "non-existing path"     "$t/nonesuch/foo"
try "file as directory"     "$t/target/foo"
cd "$t/foo"
try "relative path #1"      "bar/target"
try "relative path #2"      "../target"
try "relative path #3"      "target"
try "relative path #4"      "$t/./foo/../foobar/target"
try "relative paths"        "bar/target" "../target" "target" "$t/./foo/../foobar/target"
cd "$OLDPWD"
try "rel-base inside"       --relative-base="$t/foo" "$t/foo/bar/target"
try "rel-base inside/"      --relative-base="$t/foo/" "$t/foo/bar/target"
try "rel-base outside"      --relative-base="$t/foo/bar" "$t/foo/target"
try "rel-base name prefix"  --relative-base="$t/foo" "$t/foobar/target"
try "rel-base extra //-s"   --relative-base="$t//foo//" "$t/foo/target"
try "rel-base extra ///-s"  --relative-base="$t///foo///" "$t/foo/target"
cd "$t/foo/bar"
try "rel-base relative"     --relative-base="../../foo" "$t/foo/bar/target"
cd "$OLDPWD"
try "multiple rel-base"     --relative-base="$t/foo" \
                            "$t/foo/target" "$t/target" "$t/foo/bar/target"
try "rel-base divergent"    --relative-base="$t" "/dev/null"
try "rel-to inside"         --relative-to="$t/foo" "$t/foo/bar/target"
try "rel-to outside"        --relative-to="$t/foo/bar" "$t/target"
try "rel-to name prefix"    --relative-to="$t/foo" "$t/foobar/target"
try "rel-to extra /-s"      --relative-to="$t//foo//" "$t/foo/target"
cd "$t/foo"
try "rel-to relative"       --relative-to="../foobar" "$t/foo/target"
cd "$OLDPWD"
try "multiple rel-to"       --relative-to="$t/foo" \
                            "$t/foo/target" "$t/target" "$t/foo/bar/target"
try "combined inside both"  --relative-base="$t" --relative-to="$t/foo" "$t/foo/bar/target"
try "combined outside one"  --relative-base="$t" --relative-to="$t/foo/bar" "$t/target"
try "combined outside both" --relative-base="$t/foo" --relative-to="$t/foo/bar" "$t/target"
try "multiple combined"     --relative-base="$t/foo" --relative-to="$t/foo/bar" \
                            "$t/foo/target" "$t/target" "$t/foo/bar/target"
# -base should be a parent path of -to. If not, the arguments are ignored
try "combined errorcase"    --relative-base="$t/foo/bar" --relative-to="$t/foo" "$t/foo/bar/target"
```